# Turning off Excel Pivot Table Sub Totals VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I am creating pivot tables in VB.NET and have run into a problem I did not think would be as difficult as it is turning out. When I create a pivot table it adds in subtotals for each row and I do not want that. In excel you just drag down the subtotals option and tell it to not display subtotals. I looked into the VBA for it and it is several lines long of this format:

```
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Main Highway Pivot").PivotFields("Division"). _
    Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
    False, False)
```

This is a surprising amount of code, but that is fine, so I have been trying something similar with my pivot table in VB.NET

```
With ptTable
.ManualUpdate = True
.PivotFields("Division").orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
.PivotFields("Net Sales Amt").orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
.PivotFields("Division").Subtotals = false
.ColumnGrand = False
.RowGrand = True
.ManualUpdate = False
End With
```

I have tried several different variations of the

```
 .PivotFields("Division").Subtotals = false
```

line, but have had little luck. Is this the right code and I am specifying the false part wrong? Why is there no

```
.subtotal = false
```

to make this easier?

In any case, it seemed like something simple to me, but after a good bit of digging I am not sure how to fix it, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you as always SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a snippet of VBA (from http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/hide-subtotals-rowfields-pivot-table-t974940.html) which might help:

```
'=========================
Sub NoSubtotals()
'turns off subtotals in pivot table
'.PivotFields could be changed to
'.RowFields or .ColumnFields
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
On Error Resume Next
For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
'First, set index 1 (Automatic) to True,
'so all other values are set to False
pf.Subtotals(1) = True
pf.Subtotals(1) = False
Next pf
Next pt
End Sub
'========================
```